# Why Hibernate issued two select count statements on commit

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose the following two Entities. I'm using Bag semantics to avoid loading the entire employee collection when adding a new employee to the department.

```
public class Department {
   @Column(name = "department_id")
   private long id;
   @Column
   private String nombre;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   private Collection<Employee> employees;

   public void addEmployee(String nombreEmployee) { 
       Employee e = new Employee(nombreEmployee);
       this.employees.add(e);
       e.setDepartment(this);
   }

}

public class Employee {
    @Column(name = "employee_id") 
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String nombre;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private Department department;
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {            
     //all hibernate stuff    
     Department d = session.get(Department.class, 1l);
     d.addEmployee("John Doe");
     tx.commit();
  }
```

}

It works. It insert the new employee (due to the cascade.persist) with the deparment_id populated to the correct one. However, after tx.commit() line, Hibernate issued two statements like this: "select count(employee_id) from employee where deparment_id = ?"

Why Hibernate needs to do that?

(I can avoid those two count statements if I remove Cascade, and call the session.save(employee), but the point is to undertand the need of the two count statements)

Comment: You can set TRACE log level for org.hibernate package and check messages.

Comment: Can you post all of the SQL generated by Hibernate at the commit time?

Comment: Here are the sql statements generated at commit time: Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        employee
        (employee_id, deparment_id) 
    values
        (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(employee_id) 
    from
        employee 
    where
        department_id =?
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(employee_id) 
    from
        employee 
    where
        deparment_id =?

Comment: have you try this? pretty issue to reproduce this behaviour... thanks!

Comment: There might be something wrong with the ddl created... looks like stop doing this after I re-create the schema.